# Using wildcard * on include of apache not working on OSX

Tags: macos, apache, wildcard

Couldn't find any info about this.

tl;dr

Can't manage to include all conf files of a directory with * wildcard as `Include /path/to/directory/*.conf`

Extended explanation

I have the contents

```
$ cd /private/etc/apache2
$ tree vhosts

. vhosts 
`-- test.conf

$ cat vhosts/test.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/ml/web/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

$
```

So if I append into `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/test.conf
```

It works as expected, but if I use `*.conf`instead like:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/test.conf
```

It wont work.

This exists in an example (in `httpd.conf`), shouldn't this work? Or might be something I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

On Apache 2.4 use `IncludeOptional` instead of `Include` when using wildcards. More here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/migrating-your-apache-configuration-from-2-2-to-2-4-syntax

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While a link to a potential solution is always welcome, an answer on Stack Overflow should always contain the main parts/points of the solution in the answer body itself. Merely a link to a solution with no further commentary is not considered an acceptable answer. See [ask] on how to formulate a proper answer.